# Angular TypeScript Directive's Link method doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive

I am trying to implement a Role-Based-Access-Control system where the allowed resources will be loaded from server after login. I could manage to check it using raw JavaScript code.

```
angular.module('app').directive('accessControl',
[
    'AuthService', function (authService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: "=",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.canShow = function(resource) {
                    var allowedResources = authService.accountInfo.resources;
                    return allowedResources.indexOf(resource) !== -1;
                }

            }
        }
    }
]);
```

But since my whole application is in TypeScript, I have been trying to make the directive in pure TypeScript, but unfortunately I am unable to do so. Here is my TS code.

```
export class AccessControl implements ng.IDirective {

    public authService: App.AuthService;
    public link: (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes) => void;

    constructor(authService: App.AuthService) {
        this.authService = authService;
        console.log('authservice: ', authService);
        AccessControl.prototype.link = (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes) => {
            scope["canShow"] = function (resource: string) {
                // some logic
                console.log('can show' + resource);
                return true;
            };
        };
    }

    public static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory  {
        var directive = (authService: App.AuthService) => {
            return new AccessControl(authService);
        };

        directive['$inject'] = ['AuthService'];
        return directive;
    }

    restrict = "A";
    scope: "=";
}

angular.module('app').directive('accessControl', AccessControl.factory());
```

The link function never gets called. 
Any help or pointer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We have always declared the `link` as just a public function on the class. You don't need a public `scope` variable on your directive class unless you are using isolate scope (in which case it would be an object with each scope variable or method specifically passed). Also, you can set `$inject` directly on the `directive` without the bracket property notation you're using. Here's how we have created directives with TypeScript:

```
namespace app.directives {
    export class AccessControl implements ng.IDirective {

        public restrict = "A";

        constructor(private authService: App.AuthService) {
            console.log("authservice: ", this.authService);
        }

        public link(scope: ng.IScope, 
                    element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, 
                    attrs: ng.IAttributes) {
            console.log("in link function of directive", scope);
        }

        public static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory  {
            var directive = (authService: App.AuthService) => {
                return new AccessControl(authService);
            };

            directive.$inject = ["AuthService"];
            return directive;
        }
    }

    angular.module("app")
        .directive("accessControl", AccessControl.factory());
}
```